# UIActivityIndicatorView showing and causing crash on two specific views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I am getting a very hard to trace crash in one of my views that is related to `UIActivityIndicatorView`Sometimes it crashes right away, sometimes it takes a few loads (going back to the previous view in the navigation stack and loading the view again). I have run the app through instruments, and while memory use keeps rising, I don't see any leaks. Could I be running out of memory? I also don't see any memory warnings. Here is the error:

*** -[UIActivityIndicatorView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15f6d6aa0

I am not making any connections, and I can see the ActivityIndicator show up and then the app crashes when it disappears (or it disappears before the app crashes).

I have read that AFNetworking can cause this problem, but I am not using it. I am just using NSURLSession.

Both classes are very similar, and I have included the loading calls of one, as the class is too big to post here.

It is displayed in a Navigation Controller nested in a TabBarController:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.hairlineHeightConstraint.constant = 0.5f;
    self.hairlineDivider.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:1.0f];
    self.title = @"Course";
    [self.classroomButton setTintColor:[UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:self.passedCourse.courseColor]];
    [self.classroomButton addTarget:self action:@selector(subscribeToCourse:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self getAnySubscribedCourse];
    if (self.subscribedCourse) {
        if (self.passedCourse == self.subscribedCourse) {
            [self.classroomButton setTitle:@"Remove from Classroom" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.subscribedToThisCourse = YES;
        } else {
            self.alreadySubscribed = YES;
        }
    }
    [self configureHeaderView];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (self.shareView) {
        CGRect frame = self.shareView.frame;
        CGFloat navbarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
        frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + statusBarHeight + navbarHeight, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        self.shareView.frame = frame; 
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.shareView];
    }
    NSString *backText = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:backText style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [backButton setTitleTextAttributes:[[MSThemeManager currentTheme] barButtonTextDictionaryForState:UIControlStateNormal withTintColor:[UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:self.passedCourse.courseColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([self.tableView.tableHeaderView isKindOfClass:[ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView class]]) {
        ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView *headerView = (ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView *)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
        [headerView.courseInfoAudioPlayer stop];
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - HeaderView
- (void)configureHeaderView
{
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName : self.headerLabel.font};
    CGFloat width = screenWidth - self.headerLabel.frame.origin.x - 15.0f;
    CGSize boundingBox = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    NSString *descriptionToBound = self.passedCourse.courseDescription;
    CGRect labelRect = [descriptionToBound boundingRectWithSize:boundingBox
                                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                     attributes:attributesDictionary
                                                        context:nil];
    CGRect headerLabelRect = self.headerLabel.frame;
    CGRect tableHeaderViewRect = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    CGRect dividerRect = self.hairlineDivider.frame;
    CGFloat heightDifference = ceilf(labelRect.size.height - headerLabelRect.size.height);
    tableHeaderViewRect.size.height += heightDifference;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = tableHeaderViewRect;
    dividerRect.origin.y += heightDifference;
    headerLabelRect.size.width = ceil(labelRect.size.width);
    headerLabelRect.size.height = ceil(labelRect.size.height);
    headerLabelRect.origin.y = (dividerRect.origin.y - headerLabelRect.size.height) / 2;
    self.headerLabel.frame = headerLabelRect;
    CGFloat parallaxViewHeight = 280.0f;
    CGFloat headerHeight = parallaxViewHeight + heightDifference;
    ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView *headerView = [[ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView alloc] initWithTitleViewStyle:SWParallaxTitleViewStyleWhiteWithMask withHeight:tableHeaderViewRect.size.height headerHeight:headerHeight];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNaobj:self.passedCourse.headerImage];
    headerView.courseImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [headerView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    headerView.isTitleViewOpaque = YES;
    headerView.fadeInDuration = 0.0;
    headerView.trackID = self.passedCourse.aboutTrackID;
    [headerView courseAudioIntroControl];
    UIImage *headerTeacherImage = [UIImage imageNaobj:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.passedCourse.teacher.teacherImageID]];
    self.headerTeacherImage.image = headerTeacherImage;
    self.headerTeacherImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.headerTeacherImage.frame.size.height / 2;
    self.headerTeacherImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.headerLabel.text = self.passedCourse.courseDescription;
    [self.headerTeacherButton setImage:headerTeacherImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIView *oldHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    oldHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, oldHeaderView.frame.size.height);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    [headerView.titleView addSubview:oldHeaderView];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
    [headerView.imageContainerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:self.passedCourse.courseColor]];
    headerView.title = self.passedCourse.title;
    headerView.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu Sessions", (unsigned long)self.passedCourse.courseObjects.count];
    headerView.teacher = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"With %@", self.passedCourse.teacher.teacherName];
    [headerView.titleLabel adjustCurrentFontSize];
    [headerView.subtitleLabel adjustCurrentFontSize];
    [headerView.teacherLabel adjustCurrentFontSize];
}

#pragma mark - ScrollView

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([self.tableView.tableHeaderView isKindOfClass:[ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView class]]) {
        ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView *headerView = (ParallaxCourseDetailHeaderView *)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
        headerView.parallaxOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show where the UIActivityIndicatorView is created.

Comment: It isn't ever created, which is why I am so confused!

Comment: Then add a symbolic breakpoint on `+[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]`

Comment: No hits unfortunately. I am not starting any network connections, and I am not creating a UIActivityIndicator anywhere in my app. This makes me think it must be Parse, or GoogleAnalytics, or AWS.

Comment: Well you would still hit that method even if done in an other framework...

Comment: For some reason that I have yet to understand, this breakpoint indeed doesn't work... Use `-[UIActivityIndicatorView initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:]`

Comment: It was the Parse SDK. I was trying some different angles and I got this error: [Warning]: Attempt at runEventually command timed out. Google pointed me to Parse, and as soon as I removed the Parse calls, I stopped getting crashes. Also, that exception would not trigger for calls in frameworks.

Comment: Ok big mistake on my part. Obviously `+[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]` doesn't exist because `UIActivityIndicatorView` doesn't override `alloc`, so the implementation from `NSObject` is called most probably. But yes the one with `initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:` would be called even in frameworks.

Comment: Ok, that gets hit. How do I tell where that is getting called?